# selenium open chrome three tab with same profile

Tags: python, selenium

> python3.5 chrome59 driver has update

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import shutil

def open_chrome_in_samle(url):
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    last_dir = "%s/chrome" % current_dir
    if os.path.isdir(last_dir):
    #if exist delete folder
    shutil.rmtree(last_dir)
    #make new folder
    temp_dir = os.mkdir("%s/chrome" %current_dir)
    #open three tabs
    for index in range(3):
        print("begin create tab %s" % index)
        option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        #user data strore in special folder
        option.add_argument("--user-data-dir=%s" %temp_dir)
        option.add_argument( "--incognito")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
        print("open url")
        #the first tab get url ok,but the second tab is blank
        driver.get(url)
        print("create tab %s ok" % index)
time.sleep(20)
```

> every tab open the same url, and the configure file is the first tab

```
open_chrome_in_samle("https://www.python.org/")
```

> when start the program,the first tab can open url,but the second tab is blank

Comment: Can you consider to update the exact manual steps you trying to perform? Thanks

Comment: 1、create a folder to strore user profile  2、when the brower start at first time, it will create some configure file in the target folder 3、read the configure file in the target folder as chrome option open another tab。Thank!

Comment: in this script: chrome open the url success at first time, and the configure file created in the target folder, but open the second tab is a blank tab with no url.